# How can I redirect traffic for a specific user to connect to another server?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, tcp

what I intend to do is transfer the traffic of just a specific user  to another server (IP). with the commands below it will work very well to transfer only the traffic from the entire server, which is not what I'm looking for at the moment...

```
-m owner --uid-owner username -j
```

Server1 would be the server to redirect user traffic.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 164.server1:80
```

Server2 is the origin server where user username is to redirect to the other 164.server1.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 164.server1 --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 38.server2
```

What I've tried so far is to use the command

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -m owner --uid-owner <username> -j DNAT --to-destination 164.server1:80

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 164.server1 --dport 80 -m owner --uid-owner <username> -j SNAT --to-source 38.server2
```

more traffic was not transferred and still continue on server 38.server2.

how can i make this work?

Comment: Is this some kind of transparent proxy setup? What *traffic* are you trying to redirect? If it's the web, not much of it is going to be at port 80.

Comment: would be the user's connection traffic, in case redirecting that traffic to another server individually